# Select records with conditions in Join table or not existing in Join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following tables in a Postgres 9.5 database:

**`rate_adjust`**

```
Column     | Type    | Modifiers
-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------
id         | integer | not null default nextval('product_days_id_seq'::regclass)
name       | text    |
amount     | integer |
product_id | integer | 
type       | integer |
 Indexes:
"pk_product_days" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**`factor_calendar`**

```
 Column         |            Type             |                       Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
id              | integer                     | not null default nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass)
from_day        | integer                     |
thru_day        | integer                     |
created_at      | timestamp without time zone | default now()
updated_at      | timestamp without time zone | default now()
rate_adjust_id  | integer                     |
 Indexes:
    "pk_product" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
  Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rate_adjust" FOREIGN KEY (rate_adjust_id) REFERENCES rate_adjust(id)
```

I need the get the `rate_adjust` records which either has no `foreign_key` in the `factor_calendar` table or if they have the dates should be in `from_day` and `thru_day` range 
I am trying to use the following query but the `rate_adjust` records which are not in the range are returned as well

```
   SELECT *
   FROM rate_adjust AS rad
   LEFT JOIN factor_calendar as fc ON (
       rad.id = fc.rate_adjust_id               
      WHERE  rad.product_id = p_id  
     AND start_day_id < end_day_id AND NOT (
       ( fc.from_day > start_day_id  AND fc.from_day > end_day_id)
       OR ( fc.thru_day < start_day_id AND fc.thru_day < end_day_id)
    )
```

Data stored in `factor_calendar` is

```
 id | from_day | thru_day | rate_adjust_id     
 —--+----------+----------+----------------
  1 |       14 |       17 |              1
  2 |        1 |        3 |              2
  3 |        1 |        7 |              3
```

Data stored in `rate_adjust` is

```
 id |          name          | type | amount | product_id
—--+------------------------+------+------+------------—
  1 | rateadjust 1           |    0 |   15 |            3
  2 | rateadjust 2           |    0 |   15 |            3
  3 | rateadjust 3           |    1 |   15 |            3
  4 | rateadjust 4           |    1 |   22 |            3
```

For the above `query` with `p_id = 3` and `start_day_id = 4` and `end_day_id = 15` I expect the following rate_adjust with 
`id(s)` `1` and `2` and `4` are returned
but the ratedjust with `id` `3` is also returned

**Question**
how to modify my query to return the expected result please consider that I am also open to any suggestion to handle this in `plpgsql` language

Comment: Given your explanation, I don't understand why ids 2 and 3 would be returned.  Also, explain what "the dates should be in from_day and thru_day range" -- that is ambiguous.  Does it mean all days?  One day?  Exactly coincident?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `not exists` -- based on your explanation, but not the sample data.

That following query gets the `rate_adjust` records that have a single day in the 4-15 period:

```
select ra.*
from rate_adjust ra
where not exists (select 1
                  from factor_calendar fc
                  where fc.rate_adjust_id = ra.id and
                        fc.from_date <= 15 and
                        fc.to_date >= 4
                 );
```

Covering the whole period would be just a slight modification to the logic.

Also, this does not include `product_id`.  Your explanation doesn't mention product and it seems superfluous based on the data provided.  However, an equality condition is trivial to add.